# Trouble saving and loading mat files

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to combine a large set of images into a .mat file. The images are 512x512, grayscale. There are 31 such images.

I did the following for creating the matfile and saving it:

```
    fid1 = fopen('C:\Users\...\MATLAB\fileList_IMG.txt','r');
    PATH_IMG = 'C:\Users\...\IMAGES\';
    PATH_MAT = 'C:\Users\...\IMAGES\MATfiles\';
    IMG_DATA = zeros(512, 512, 31);
    while ~feof(fid1)
        folderName = fgetl(fid1);

        for i=1:31
            fileName = sprintf('%s%s\\%s\\%s_%02d.png',PATH_IMG, folderName, folderName, folderName, i);
            tempImg = imread(fileName);
            IMG_DATA(:,:,i) = tempImg(:,:,1);
        end

        save_fileName = sprintf('%s%s', PATH_MAT, folderName);
        save(save_fileName, 'IMG_DATA');
    end
```

I did the following for loading the matfile back:

```
     fileName = 'C:\Users\...\IMAGES\MATfiles\balloon.mat';
     NEWIMG_DATA = load(fileName);
```

Lets say that this is new_IMG_DATA for sake of readability.

I notice that the values are different! Its not like the values were scaled up because values of 170 and 172 in IMG_DATA correspond to 3709 and 3666 in new_IMG_DATA. Both, IMG_DATA and new_IMG_DATA are of double data type. if I force IMG_DATA to uint8 before creating the .mat file, most of the values of new_IMG_DATA are 255.

Here are some samples of IMG_DATA before saving it as a matfile:
IMG_DATA(400,400,4:10)

ans(:,:,1) =
   133

ans(:,:,2) =
   141

ans(:,:,3) =
   142

ans(:,:,4) =
   145

ans(:,:,5) =
   156

ans(:,:,6) =
   157

ans(:,:,7) =
   158

Here is a sample of new_IMG_DATA after loading it back:
NEWIMG_DATA.IMG_DATA(400,400,4:10)

ans(:,:,1) =
       16366

ans(:,:,2) =
       18216

ans(:,:,3) =
       19648

ans(:,:,4) =
       19578

ans(:,:,5) =
       19203

ans(:,:,6) =
       18682

ans(:,:,7) =
       17123

I want to able to save and load the .mat file properly. How do I this?

Comment: You'll need to create a very short example of code that reproduces this error, since its very uncommon for MATLAB to have an error in load/save.  Show the valyes before SAVE, and the values after SAVE in the code snippet.  If this is a real MATLAB bug, you should be able to reproduce in a very simple way

Comment: Is this a multispectral image from the CAVE database? These images come in 16bit so it is kinda expected that they range from 0 to 65535. You should try tempImg = double(imread(fileName))/255.;

Comment: Can you please try `im2double` when reading the images? What version of Matlab are you using? In your preferences, what is the format you save your mat files? If you change these settings, does it affects the saved data?

Comment: @ypnos: Yes. And thank you for point it out that it is 16 bpp. When I open the image in IrfanView, I keep getting 512x512x8BPP. So I had assumed it was 8BPP. Anyways, I did this when reading back the matfile:  new_IMG_DATA = uint8(new_IMG_DATA./255);

Comment: You should check out my software to inspect multispectral images: http://gerbil.sf.net

Comment: @ypnos, you made Gerbil! Awesome! I have used it for sometime now and its pretty good!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the comments above. ypnos pointed out that the data is of 16 bpp rather than 8 bpp as I had assumed.